# Given a location in the US, how can I see the average air quality during a given month/week/day based on historical data?

Tags: usa, online-resources, health, history, air-quality

Knowing the information  will help me decide where/when to go, and whether I should bring some air-related equipment (mask, air purifier, etc.).

What I have unsuccessfully tried so far:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle#Climate) typically doesn't show the average air quality during a given month/week/day based on historical data.

Comment: I can't imagine how knowing average data over the last X years helps you deciding whether you need to wear a mask tomorrow. Despite your first paragraph, I find this question completely off-topic.

Comment: @littleadv useful to decide and prepare a trip ahead of time. Eg I don't want to commit to go to some place in two months if it's known to be typically very polluted then.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about travel.

Comment: @Midavalo preparing for the local conditions is an important part of traveling. Many questions have been asked in that spirit eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61616

Comment: The American Lung Association analyses data from official air quality monitors to compile the State of the Air report, https://www.lung.org/research/sota Its reports are searchable by state, county, and metropolitan statistical area

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt on the contrary - that question you've linked asks about a specific place, time, and a travel-related purpose.  Your question, however,  is incredibly broad and would probably be more on topic on a weather related site rather than travel.

Comment: @Midavalo The previous complain was that the question is off-topic. The question I've linked shows it is not. Your new "too broad" complain is addressed in the current answer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Your question has nothing to do with travel.  It's off-topic.  The question you've linked is about travel, therefore on-topic.  The broadness of your question makes it even less on-topic.  The downvotes on both your question and your answer would indicate that the community doesn't believe it's a great fit.  You could attempt to [edit] them both to make them more on topic

Comment: @Midavalo "Your question has nothing to do with travel" -> Knowing the information will help me decide where/when to go, and whether I should bring some air-related equipment (mask, air purifier, etc.).  Eg I don't want to commit to go to some place in two months if it's known to be typically very polluted then. Why do you think it has nothing to do with travel?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

https://www.epa.gov/outdoor-air-quality-data/air-data-tile-plot:

> Plot daily AQI values for a specific location and time period. Each square or “tile” represents one day of the year and is color-coded based on the AQI level for that day. The legend tallies the number of days in each AQI category.

[image]

They also make all the data available as a CSV file for each year, so one can compute the daily/weekly/monthly trend by averaging over several years.

---

[airnow.gov](https://www.airnow.gov/state/?name=washington) gives the air quality for a given day in different locations in a US state in the past. Downside: doesn't give directly a clear daily/weekly/monthly trend.

[image]